# Catch-all command that creates a field (if non-existant) with the right schema in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My user collection is defined to be permitted to look like this:

```
{
    _id: String,
    questions: [Object]
}
```

Inside the `questions` it will look like this (example):

```
[
    {
        questionId: 'f93uf0auf'
        answer: ["yes", "maybe"]
    },
    {
        questionId: 'avka+0uf'
        answer: ["no"]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to find a catch-all command to this collection and cover the following bases:

- Should create the `questions` field if it doesn't exist.
- Needs to create an array from the start because that is the only allowed format.
- Should be able to add to the `answer` set.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Users.update({_id: userId, 'questions.questionId': questionId}, {$addToSet: {'questions.$.answer': answer}})
```

However, this doesn't create the field if it doesn't exist. `upsert` doesn't work either.

Is there a catch-all command?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find one way to meet your requirement through `$addToSet`, here is one way to do that through command as bellow.

```
> db.questions
    .find({_id: userId})
    .forEach(function(doc) { 
        if (!doc.questions) {
            doc['questions'] = []
        }; 

        var exist = false; 
        doc.questions.map(function(e) { 
            if (e.questionId && (e.questionId == questionId)){ 
                e.answer.push(answer); 
                exist = true;
            }
        });
        if (!exist) {
            doc.questions.push({questionId: questionId, answer: [answer]});
        } 

        db.questions.save(doc);
    });
```

Comment: No this will just create a new object with the same `questionId` and different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your query criteria is really catching an object? And does the *question* object exist when you try to update it?

Because I have tested your update query, and it does create the *answer* field when it doesn't exist. The official documentation confirms that as well.

> If the field is absent in the document to update, $addToSet creates the array field with the specified value as its element.

It used this very object to test it, adding the *answer* field to the second *question* successfully.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c9d76e2318c31cb70f9c55"),
    "questions" : [
        {
            "questionId" : "f93uf0auf",
            "answer" : [ "yes" ]
        },
        {
            "questionId" : "f93uf0aug"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `question` field, not the `answer`.

Comment: Oh, right. I don't think you can do that in a single update.